# Are static data members value initialized?

Tags: c++

Must I provide an explicit initializer for the definition of `static` members of integral type outside the class body, or can I safely omit that? Omitting the initializer and accessing the value seems to return a value of `0` every time, this implies that it is indeed value initialized and can be omitted. What does the standard say about this?

Comment: "seems" is a weak guarantee, it might depend on the compiler and optimization flags of the compiler

Comment: [initialization#Non-local_variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables).

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: And care to [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)

Answer (score 1):

Static members of the class are entities with external linkage. The compiler expects you to define that entity in some translation unit. The whole purpose of this feature is to give you the opportunity to choose that translation unit. The compiler cannot choose it for you. It is, again, a part of your intent, something you have to tell the compiler.

In early C++ it was allowed to define the static data members inside the class which certainly violate the idea that class is only a blueprint and does not set memory aside. This has been dropped now.

Putting the definition of static member outside the class emphasize that memory is allocated only once for static data member (at compile time). Each object of that class doesn't have it own copy.

Starting from C++17 you can declare your static members as inline. This eliminates the need for a separate definition. By declaring them in that fashion you effectively tell the compiler that you don't care where this member is physically defined and, consequently, don't care about its initialization order.